# How do I get classes from my course to work with my program?

Tags: java

I'm trying to go through the course/textbook described at the link below, which uses the libraries at the link below. I am trying to write a little test program, which uses the `stdout.java` and `stdin.java` libraries.

I am using the windows terminal window with the `java development kit`.

So i have a program, `test.java`, which calls `stdin.java`.

I have `test.java`, `stdin.java` and `stdout.java` in the same directory. I type in `javac stout.java` and I get no error messages, but when I type in `javac stdin.java` I get

> error: cannot find symbol StdOut.println();

and If I haven't turned `stdin.java` into a class file (using javac stdin.java) I can run test.java

[Stdlib](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/)

Comment: check this  https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/classpath.html, you need to add class path variable, så your java program can find it from your system. You might need to restart your computer after doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your complied `StdOut` class is not in the *class path*. There are a couple of ways you can resolved this.

1. Add the directory where your complied classes are to your class path.
2. When you compile, specify the class path using the `-cp` option.

So for example, you could run the following to compile StdOut and then compile StdIn (assuming you class files are all in the same directory):

```
javac StdOut.java
javac -cp * StdIn.java
```

Here is more information on [Setting the class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)